# How to scroll to bottom of the ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, cordova

I have developed one application using PhoneGap. In my application I have displayed a number of elements in a listview using `ui` `li`. Here I want to scroll to the last element in list. For that i have used following code,

```
$('#dates li').last().addClass('active-li').focus();
$('#dates li').last().focus();
```

I have used this one also,

```
$('#dates').scrollTop($('#dates li:nth-child(14)').position().top);;
```

extra class is adding but focus is not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the [`tabindex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex) attribute:

```
<li tabindex="1"></li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/GEsmb/

Because you can not focus on `li`. It's not a text field or button or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').scrollTop($('ul li').last().position().top + $('ul li').last().height());
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/GEsmb/1/

Answer (score 3):

Try [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/):

```
$('#dates').scrollTop($('#dates').height())
```

or:

```
$('#dates').scrollTop($('#dates')[0].scrollHeight);
```

if your list has lots of content.