# AngularApp: How can I show the last message in a conversation?

Tags: angular

I am making an application in angular and I have integrated a chat.
As you can see in the screenshot, when my chat loads it shows the first message each time.

what can i do so that when it loads it shows me the part with the last message?

Screenshots:

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMAaI.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y02Nh.png)

I also quote the HTML code:

```
<div class="msg_history">
        <li class="message" *ngFor="let message of messages">
          <div
            *ngIf="
              message.receiver_username == myUserName;
              then incoming_msg;
              else outgoing_msg
            "
          ></div>
          <ng-template #incoming_msg>
            <div class="incoming_msg">
              <div class="incoming_msg_img">
                <img
                  src="https://i.imgur.com/k2PZLZa.png"
                  alt="User avatar"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="received_msg">
                <div class="received_withd_msg">
                  <h5>{{message.timestamp | date : 'medium':'GMT'}}</h5>
                  <p>{{ message.message }}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #outgoing_msg>
            <div class="outgoing_msg">
              <div class="sent_msg">
                <h5>{{message.timestamp | date : 'medium':'GMT'}}</h5>
                <p>{{ message.message }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
        </li>
      </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the tabIndex property of the li HTML item? Check out this link to see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757144/how-to-scroll-to-bottom-of-the-ul. You can bind the tabIndex property to a variable you maintain in the TS code, which is the last element of the array.

Comment: Did u tried to sort them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try somehting like this:

```
 <li id="liMessages" #liMessages class="message" *ngFor="let message of messages">
```

Then this in your TS code after you bind the messages array:

```
document.getElementById("liMessages").tabIndex = this.messages.length;
```

Or

```
document.getElementById("liMessages").setAttribute("tabindex", "6");
```

You can find an alternative approach by scrolling the ul here:

[How to scroll to li element in a ul list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864901/how-to-scroll-to-li-element-in-a-ul-list)